# Convert a byte to 8 booleans

Tags: c, boolean, byte, bit, shift

I wondered how can I take an 8 bit variable,
and break it apart to 8 booleans, for a 'for' loop.
For example:

```
void byteWrite(byte byteIn)
{
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    PORTA |= 128; // STHP ON
    if(?)
      PORTB |= 4; //STCP ON
    else
      PORTB &=11;// STCP OFF
    _delay_ms(1);
    PORTA &= 63; // STHP OFF
    _delay_ms(1);
  }
  PORTB |= 2; // DS ON
  _delay_ms(1);
  PORTB &= 1; // DS OFF
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bitwise-and, with shifts:

```
if((byteIn & (1 << i)) != 0)
```

This simply computes the bitmask `(1 << i)` for each step in the loop, and uses bitwise-and (the `&` operator) to check if the corresponding bit in `byteIn` is set.

This is a very common thing to do.

If you're worried about re-computing the mask on every iteration, you can use the constant mask `1` (i.e. check only the rightmost bit) and instead shift `byteIn` on each iteration:

```
if((byteIn & 1) != 0)
 ...
else
 ...
byteIn >>= 1;
```

The final line shifts `byteIn` one bit to the right, so that on the next iteration the and checks the next bit. This *can* be faster, since it is somewhat simpler in machine code (particularly for smaller processors, this looks like PIC code).

Note that both solutions above iterate from the least-significant (right-most) bit first, if that's not appropriate you need to reverse it of course.

Comment: If optimized versions are an issue, the following link is an additional valuable resource https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Yeah, seems legit I will test it out on my IC.

Comment: By the way, I never understood the << methods, any link to a tutorial about it? ;)

Comment: @user2054911 Any C reference manual should do ... `byteIn >>= 1;` is just a short way of writing `byteIn = byteIn >> 1;` (that holds for all of them, i.e. `+=`, `-=` and so on, too).

Comment: @user2054911 You're probably trying to use `11111111` as a binary literal, but that's a decimal value. C doesn't have binary literals. Use `255` or `0xff`. Note that the lowest byte of `11111111` is `0xc7` which is `0b11000011` in binary (`0b` prefix for clarity, that's *NOT* valid in C).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(uint8_t mask = 1<<7; mask!=0; mask>>=1)
{
  if(data & mask)
  {
    PORT |= mask;
  } 
  else
  {
    PORT &= ~mask;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user2054911 This is really such fundamental stuff that no explanation should be necessary, given that you know how the bitwise operators work. If you don't, you'll obviously not be able to write or understand a program like this. Google "C bitwise operators".